# View-based NSOutlineView row badges

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm still struggling with the View-Based NSOutlineViews introduced with OSX Lion. While everything works quite good now, I'd like to add Mail.app-like unread badges to rows.

Is there a better way for View-Based NSOutlineViews than following the example of `-(void)drawBadgeForRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex inRect:(NSRect)badgeFrame` in [PXSourcelist](https://github.com/Perspx/PXSourceList/blob/master/Classes/PXSourceList.m) ?

Thanks, Bucks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anybody encounters the same problem, I've found a solution in the Lion release notes that is actually quite simple.

First subclass `NSTableCellView`, add an `IBOutlet` for an `NSButton` and a `@synthesize`/`@property` statement to it. Then open the `NSTableCellView` that should have a badge in Interface Builder. Set it's class to your newly created subclass and add a button to it. Set the button style to `"inline"` and it's type to `"switch"`.

Now select the `NSTableCellView` again and connect the `NSButton` `IBOutlet` to your added button. 
That's it. You can now call e.g. `[[cellView button] setTitle@"123"]]` to set the rows badge label to `123` or any arbitrary string.

Comment: Here’s the sample code from Apple where you can see it in action: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SidebarDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010893-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2